# text under symbols in the sidebar menu

Tags: python, html, css, django

Very new to CSS and HTML, but right now working on Django one-page project.
Under icons, I would like to place some text, but there is an issue with the borders.

[image: sample img]

Right now text wrapping works not very well, I would like to center text under the icon and have at least 3 or 4 straight strings.
Maybe there are issues that this text and icons should be in the container, IDK, will be very happy to hear any solution and suggestions for my portfolio project.
Thank you!

Here is my HTML:

```css
body {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534258936925-c58bed479fcb?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=889&q=80) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

#background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 260px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.social-menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.social-menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.social-menu ul li .fab {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 75px;
  transition: .5s;
}

.social-menu ul li .fab:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.social-menu ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: translate(0, 0px);
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.social-menu ul li a:hover {
  transform: rotate(0deg) skew(0deg) translate(0, -10px);
}

.social-menu ul li:nth-child(1) a:hover {
  background-color: #FF3371;
}

.social-menu ul li:nth-child(2) a:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

.social-menu ul li:nth-child(3) a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

.title {
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-top: 220px;
  margin-left: 445px;
}

.icons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  color: red;
}

.icons li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 140px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.icons-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 76%;
  left: 52%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.icons-text li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 100px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> {% load static %}
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5476287230.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="social-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/kseniia_ifbb_latvia"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@kseniiasherr"><i class="fab fa-tiktok"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100009190064504"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <h1>ЧТО ВЫ ПОЛУЧАЕТЕ?</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="background"></div>

  <div class="icons">
    <li><i class="fas fa-utensils"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fas fa-dumbbell"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fas fa-clock"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fas fa-heartbeat"></i></li>
  </div>

  <div class="icons-text">
    <li>
      <h1>План питания с учетом Ваших вкусовых потребностей</h1>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h1>Тренировки для любого уровня подготовки</h1>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h1>Максимально быстрые результаты</h1>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h1>Тело, о котором Вы могли только мечтать</h1>
    </li>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you need something like this? https://imgur.com/Ylf6JMk

Comment: Yes, Exactly. Perfect

Comment: Please share the solution, and I don't understand why on your screenshot social media buttons and a white background touch each other, and the title not on the middle

Comment: If you run the code snippet, that is how it is already: https://imgur.com/BC5qDRP

Comment: Even if I provide you a solution, there would be problems. You should not be using absolute positioning and padding or margins but a grid system. Please try to use a template for your portfolio and then implement it: https://onepagelove.com/templates/free-templates

Comment: @m4n0 thank you. It's a completely new topic for me, I will learn and update my project. Have a nice day